# JTDS issues with SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, tomcat, web, jtds

I have two Java web applications deployed on Tomcat that connect to SQL Server Database using Windows Authentication with JTDS.

The first application that connects to the database works fine, but the second throws the error:
java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: SSO Failed: Native SSPI library not loaded. Check the java.library.path system property.

It seems that the first application is hanging the ntlmauth.dll and then the second application can't use it.

Any help is welcome. Thank you

Comment: Found the solution on another question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637585/native-library-sqljdbc-auth-dll-already-loaded-in-another-classloader