# sqljdbc_auth.dll already loaded in another classloader in Mule standalone server

Tags: jdbc, mule, windows-authentication, spring-jdbc

I have a Mule Standalone server, I have two Mule Deployable Archives that I created in MuleStudio, both connect to SQL Server and use integrated authentication.  Whichever archive I deploy first works, and the second archive will fail with this message:

```
Apr 30, 2013 8:37:39 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI <clinit>
WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : Native Library C:\MuleCE\mule-standalone-3.3.1\lib\boot\sqljdbc_auth.dll already loaded in another classloader

Root Exception was: Cannot get connection for URL jdbc:sqlserver://SQL01;instanceName=APPS;databaseName=muletest;integratedSecurity=true : This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:b4032f04-ddb4-464e-8b32-cd36e1882018(SQL Code: 0, SQL State: + null). Type: class java.sql.SQLException
ERROR 2013-04-30 08:37:54,061 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get connection for URL jdbc:sqlserver://SQL01;instanceName=APPS;databaseName=muletest;integratedSecurity=true : This driver is not configured for integrated authentication.
```

I don't quite know how this works so if I'm not on the right track let me know, but I believe my problem is related to this question
[Native Library sqljdbc_auth.dll already loaded in another classloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637585/native-library-sqljdbc-auth-dll-already-loaded-in-another-classloader) so it looks like I need place sqljdbc_auth.dll in a shared library.  My question is where should I put it under Mule?  Under the mule-standalone-3.3.1\lib folder there are: boot, endorsed, mule, opt, shared, and user.

Also, how do I tell my project to reference that shared library when it creates the mule deployable archive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied sqljdbc4.jar and sqljdbc_auth.dll to the mule-standalone-3.3.1 installation folder under lib\opt and lib\shared\default, restarted the mule service and it appears to work now.  I could not find documentation on the purposes of all the sub-folders under lib so I don't if this is best practice or if there is a best practice.