# SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication

Tags: java, sql-server, gwt, jdbc, jboss

I am building a GWT application that queries SQL Server. While working in Eclipse everything is fine and dandy, but when I try to deploy a .war file and stick it into a JBoss deployments directory, I get this error:

> Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : Native Library
>   JBossServerPath\bin\sqljdbc_auth.dll already loaded in another
>   classloader com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This
>   driver is not configured for integrated authentication.
>   ClientConnectionId:450886fa-8bde-4f52-b213-7af1f4948913

If I remove the sqljdbc4.jar from my project directory and have the sqljdbc_auth.dll in the JBossPath\bin directory as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10645025/5031373), I get the following error.

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=DataBase;integratedSecurity=true;

Also, I can't find the lib directory referenced in the above answer.

I have the sqljdbc4.jar in my project's WEB-INF\lib directory and I'm building the project with ant.

I tried asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31032103/5031373) earlier, but it got marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10637585/5031373), which did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I didn't have the line `Dependencies: com.microsoft.sqlserver` in my Manifest.MF file.