# This driver is not configured for integrated authentication

Tags: java, sql-server, servlets, glassfish, sqljdbc

Trying to connect my java web application with MS-SQL server using `sqljdbc41` for `jdk 1.8`. Here is the database connection code-

```
    Connection connection;
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Lista;integratedSecurity=true";
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

when i am trying to insert some values to the database like-

```
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO user_informations VALUES(?,?,?)");

    ps.setString(1, "value");
    ps.setString(2, "value");
    ps.setString(3, "value");

    ps.executeUpdate();
```

getting the following error each time-

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not
>   configured for integrated authentication

Here are some informations about what i have tried yet-

- i have added the path of `sqljdbc41` in the path variable.
- i have added the path of `sqljdbc_auth.dll` in the path variable.
- i have added the `sqljdbc41.jar` into my `Nebeans` project library.
- i have added the `sqljdbc_auth.dll` into both bin folder under `jdk` and `jre`.
- my `jdk` is `64 bit` under program files folder not in program file(x86).
- jdbc driver folder is also in program file directory.
- sql server and sql server browser services are also running.

**Edit**

Now i experiencing a new thing-after restarting my pc when i deploy the project for the first time then it is working perfectly but when i make any change in my code and re-run the project it's not working!

Comment: Look at this link: [JDBC 4.x: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2015/01/09/jdbc-this-driver-is-not-configured-for-integrated-authentication.aspx).  ALSO: Are you running a 32-bit or 64-bit JVM?  Exactly where did you get sqljdbc_auth.dll: from the 32-bit or 64-bit Windows folder?

Comment: i already saw this, but it wasn't helpful for me! i putted sqljdbc_auth.dll from `program files` directory. isn't it windows 64bit folder?

Comment: Have you looked at all the suggestions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277001/dll-missing-in-jdbc ?

Comment: This answer help me 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637585/native-library-sqljdbc-auth-dll-already-loaded-in-another-classloader?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem!

The error (described in my question above) i was getting because the `glassfish` server had not any access on `sqljdbc42.jar` file. so i have placed the `sqljdbc42.jar` file into my `glassfish` server in this location-

`glassfish-4.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib`

And it's now working perfectly.

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 4):

`sqljdbc_auth.dll` is need to use windows authentication or Kerberos authentication.

Get the dll from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) and install it either by:

1. drop on application library folder
2. drop on the java bin folder (attention if you have multiple java installations)
3. drop the library on some folder and then add the path in the command line:

   ```
   java -Djava.library.path=<library path>...
   ```

The mssql-jdbc driver and the auth dll should be:

- on the same folder (but not mandatory)
- both from the same version
- for the same architecture (x86/x64) JVM is running.

Check also the jdbc compatibility matrix with java versions on the download page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that there were 2 java installations, one of them was the standard installation and it was 64bit, the other one was included in my oracle jdeveoper installation (it was the one used by the application giving that error) and surprisingly it was 32bit.
I just put the correct dll in the java installation used by my application and everything went well