# nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, jpa

1. I am getting error Native Library 
   `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27\bin\sqljdbc_auth.dll` already loaded in another classloader along with Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is

   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection

   I have already seen Native Library `sqljdbc_auth.dll` already loaded in another classloader page and applied the changes mentioned here like copying `sqljdbc_auth.dll`(C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x64 because My JDK is 64-bit and windows is also 64-bit) into `tomcat/bin` and `sqljdbc4-4.0`(from my project target folder) into `tomcat/lib` but still facing the issue again and again. Please help me out.
2. Also i have the below doubt
        i) sqljdbc*.jar should be considered from which path? either from my project target folder or from C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu (2 jars found here - sqljdbc.jar, sqljdbc4.jar)

   ii) Also i could see 2 versions of SQL server installed in my machine i.e Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server and Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.0 for SQL Server so which one i have to consider
               if i have to consider 6.0 then again which jar i have to take because C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_6.0\enu\jre7 - sqljdbc41.jar is there and in C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_6.0\enu\jre8 - sqljdbc42.jar is there

Comment: Try to put the mysql JDBC driver JAR on your classpath

Comment: Hi, Could you please see my edits and help me out

Comment: Having multiple JDBC driver on your path is not good, remove one of them and choose the one that is more suitable with hibernate, spring versions etc..

Comment: Could you please tell which version of SQL server my application is using because i could see Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server and Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.0 for SQL Server were installed in my machine

Comment: have a look here https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=11774 each driver got some system requirements, so depending on your system you need to pick the right driver.

Comment: i am using 'Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.0' . My jdk version is 1.8 and it is 64 bit, please tell me which sqljdbc*.jar have to take to copy in tomcat/lib as i mentioned above 2 sqljdbc.jar files i could see in my folder path.

Comment: It tells you on the link I have sent, you need sqljdbc42.jar if you are using Java Runtime Environment (JRE) 8.0.

Comment: Yes, but still facing the same issue sqljdbc_auth.dll already loaded in another class loader

Comment: ERROR: 2017-05-10 11:55:26,589 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000319: Could not get database metadata
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:92969147-4947-4e51-9109-82685749e1bf

Comment: Hello, can anyone answer this question please..

Comment: Also my Test Connection was also not succeed - Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:sqlserver://XXX:1433;databaseName=XXX;integratedSecurity=true; using com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:5c625385-6cbd-44f7-8229-12a628ab62fb)

Comment: Hi justMe, could you please answer this

Comment: Hi, you really need to do some research in regards of this configurations, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536608/this-driver-is-not-configured-for-integrated-authentication or https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2015/01/09/jdbc-this-driver-is-not-configured-for-integrated-authentication/ for your latest error