Using gMSA account for SQL Server JDBC connection
Is it possible to use gMSA account for SQL Server JDBC connection in my own java application?
If possible please anyone can help me though the steps?
I am trying to start my java application on Windows services after changing the Logon to gMSA account but the service haven't been started. It didn't throw any error though. No idea what was wrong.

Did you give the gMSA account permission to log in? It's just a domain account like any other, you need to CREATE LOGIN and CREATE USER for it (you probably want to just add it to an AD group and create a login for that group). And then you use Windows Authentication (aka Integrated Security) without a username and password to connect. What is your current connection string?

@Charlieface
jdbc:sqlserver://mssql-machine1.mssqlkerberos.com:1433;databaseName=master;domain=mssqlkerberos;userName=svc_sql$;driverName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;integratedSecurity=true
I am getting the below error now
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:0b2c80f7-264d-4aca-a2c4-694b69accf28
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mssql-jdbc_auth-8.4.1.x64 in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1875)

Possibly relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59331306/14868997 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/45802582/14868997

No. Loading the mssql-jdbc_auth-8.4.1.x64.dll will authenticate the locally installed sql server via NTLM even though the credentials are wrong

There is no such thing as "wrong" creds for Integrated Authentication because username and password are not used. The currently logged in user's existing ticket or hash is used. For NTLM it's the hash (so the password must be the same on client and server) and for Kerberos with AD the domain controller is contacted. It sounds like you are trying to use AD credentials but the server is not joined to the domain, or some other AD issue.

I am giving gMSA account as username with empty password which throws the error
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:0b2c80f7-264d-4aca-a2c4-694b69accf28 Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mssql-jdbc_auth-8.4.1.x64 in java.library.path at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1875)

That's a 4-year old driver, the latest version is 12.8. Like I said, you shouldn't need to pass the username, the username and password are ignored. The Java application needs to be running as the gMSA user on a domain joined machine, and the JDBC driver needs to be loaded, and the SQL Server machine needs to be joined to the domain as well (with an SPN), and a LOGIN and USER need to be created as mentioned. If you've done all those it should all work.
