# JBoss: Native Library sqljdbc_auth.dll already loaded in another classloader

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jboss, windows-authentication

**UPDATE**: This unanswered question on jboss forums, is another way of describing my exact problem: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/199888

**Original post**:I am trying to make integrated authentication work on web applications deployed to JBoss 7.x. I have successfully made one work, by copying sqljdbc_auth.dll into either Windows/System32, or {java location}/jre/bin. However, if two or more applications are running, I will get an error saying that `Native Library sqljdbc_auth.dll already loaded in another classloader`

I know why this error is happening, and [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10645025/1203811) has a Tomcat solution. But I can't make it work in JBoss. Actually, putting the dll inside the jboss/bin folder gives the exact same error as before:

```
Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : 
Native Library C:\Jboss-eap-7.0\bin\sqljdbc_auth.dll already loaded in another classloader
```

**How do I configure JBoss, and/or place the `sqljdbc_auth.dll`?**

My deployments are not located under any module, or named server instance. I think it's simply called standalone

I have tried this approach as well, but I can not figure out where to put the jar file, in the JBoss directories. I tried deploying it as a deployment like the web applications, and I tried copying it into the lib folder, under standalone. No success.

**EDIT:**

I am trying to implement a global module, as per the answer posted, but get following error now:

```
14:00:25,333 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 121)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver from 
[Module "deployment.MyWebapp.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you must have created a module for sql jdbc driver something like this.

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.microsoft.sqlserver">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="sqljdbc.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

And added this module as dependency to each of your deployed application.

I would suggest to declare this module as global module by editing the standalone.xml file like this ..

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:4.0">
            <global-modules>
                <module name="com.microsoft.sqlserver" slot="main"/>
                 .
                 .
            </global-modules>
.
.
</subsystem>
```

And remove the dependency to this module from your individual applications.

Comment: I know nothing about modules. Could you add which xml file you are refering to in the first code example? I have not added any modules whatsoever. The sqljdbc was first implemented inside the war-files, and later just defined as scope=provided in my project pom.xml (maven).

Comment: The module definition may be either in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` or in a separate `module.xml` file in `<JBOSS INSTALLATION>\modules\com\microsoft\sqlserver\main`.

Comment: @KjetilNordin - The directory structure under <JBOSS INSTALLATION>\modules\ folder may vary depending on the name of module.

Comment: I tried to implement it under the modules folder, and it's own module.xml. There is no cigar yet, but a whole lot of new error messages I need to sort through. It might take a while, but I'll get back soon. Anyways, thanks for this answer. I feel like it put me on the right track to solve my problem, so I'm optimistic.

Comment: I get a ClassNotFoundException (see updated question for details)

Comment: Ok, I made it work. I read a bit more about modules, but found that the reason I couldn't get it to work right away, was some typos I made. Your solution works perfectly. Thank you very much!