# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library sqljdbc_auth.dll already loaded in another classloader

Tags: java, sql-server, tomcat

I have multiple applications that needs to connect to MSSQL using windows authentication.

The First webApp which is loaded works fine. but the remaining fail prompting

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library $tomcat/bin/sqljdbc_auth.dll already loaded in another classloader
```

Below is the code used

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
connection= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=XXX;integratedSecurity=true");
```

**I Have placed 
        sqljdbc*.jar --> tomcat*/lib  and sqljdbc_auth.dll --> tomcat*/bin**

Seems like all my applications are trying to load the shared lib($tomcat/bin/dll) multiple times. Hence the first load works and the remaining fail.

**Edit: I understand that the native library (DLL) can only be loaded into the JVM once, hence the error, but I after looking around the net I still have no solution.**

How can i load the dll only once?

Please Help!!

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10645025/2131576

Comment: as mentioned i have already placed the files to the particular folders. But still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess. That removing the line

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

would solve the problem.

As mentioned in the javadoc of [DriverManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html)

> The DriverManager methods `getConnection` and `getDrivers` have been enhanced to support the Java Standard Edition [Service Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Service%20Provider) mechanism.
>   ...
>   Applications no longer need to explictly load JDBC drivers using `Class.forName()`.

**edit** This requires a jdbc driver which supports the JDBC 4.0 API. Which should be the case from Microsoft JDBC driver 4.0 on (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/system-requirements-for-the-jdbc-driver)

A matrix which Microsoft JDBC driver supports which SQL server version you can find at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server-support-matrix

Comment: That throws an exception     
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=xxx;integratedSecurity=true

Comment: @divyakrishna This would mean the driver you are using does not support the JDBC 4.0 API. You could update the driver. I updated my answer with some additional information.

Comment: In my case the driver version and jar matches perfectly. 

When loading tomcat with only a single web application (anyone), the web application successfully connect to the DB. That's the reason i don't think its about versioning.

Comment: @divyakrishna Could you have a look in the `sqljdbc*.jar` if it contains the file `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver`. If not, your used driver doesn't support the JDBC 4.0 API (see the javadoc of DriverManager). Btw. Which Microsoft JDBC driver version are you using?

Comment: Issue is resolved. Thanks. 

I have removed the jar from WEB-INF/lib in all my application. And placed only in tomcat for sharing the native lib. Its working now.